# $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)$ is not valid for non-monotone function.

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)$ is not valid for non-monotone function. How to find such a counterexample?

As is well-known, for monotone function $f$, we have $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)$. then for non-monotone function, is there any simple example such that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ exists (or for any $\delta>0$, $f$ is integrable on $[\delta, 1]$, and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_\delta^1 f(x)dx$ exists), but $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)$ is not valid.

Comment: Monotone is much stronger than needed—continuous is enough to establish the limit, and even that is a bit stronger than needed.

Comment: @Khosrotash Oh, we need $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ exists.

Comment: It's valid for all Riemann-integrable functions. If the integral exists only as an improper integral, monotony would guarantee the limit, nonetheless. If the integrand has a singularity with oscillating behavior, you may have a counterexample, e.g. $f(x)=\frac1x\sin\frac1x$.

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable then the limit exists and equals the intergal. So there is no counter-example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Or $f$ is generalized Riemann integral.

Comment: Just take $f(x) =x-x^2$. It's not monotonous on $[0,1]$, but the limit of the sums exists and is equal to the integral.

Comment: @ProfessorVector How to show that for $f(x)=1/x \sin 1/x$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}f(i/n)$ does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure it doesn't, but counterexamples can only be of that type, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for $m = 0,1,2,\ldots$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}2^m,&x = 2^{-m}\\0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}f\left( \frac{k}{2^n}\right)\left(\frac{k}{2^n}- \frac{k-1}{2^n}\right) = 2^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}f\left( \frac{k}{2^n}\right) = 2^{-n}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{2^n}{2^r}= 2 - \frac{2}{2^{n+1}},$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n = 2 \neq 0 = \int_0^1f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: We have an improper integral here -- since $f$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$.